# Apache Flink: How to process all the events that are behind a watermark?

Tags: apache-flink, watermark, flink-streaming

I want to use Flink's event timestamp and plan to implement a simple emitWatermark which is System.currentTimeInMillis - 10 secs. My understanding is tumbling window will fire start_time + window_interval + 10 secs. So if events arrives later than the watermark those events will be dropped.

Is there a way to write all the dropped events by Flink to a sink like S3?

Answer (score 3):

It should be achievable with [Side Outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/side_output.html). The documentation of the `sideOutputLateData` operator states the following:

> Send late arriving data to the side output identified by the given {@link OutputTag}. Data
>        is considered late after the watermark has passed the end of the window plus the allowed
>        lateness set using {@link #allowedLateness(Time)}.

So then you can get the late data stream by the output tag and sink it to s3.

Comment: It may be good to show the specific method, essentially `windowedStream.sideOutputLateData(someOutputTag)` and then `outputStream.getSideOutput(someOutputTag)` which gets you another `DataStream` you can do whatever you want with